# Is there a better, performant way to display LaTeX formatted math-text in Kivy?

Tags: python, math, text, kivy, latex

Here's basically what I use (minus the imports):

```py
fig = figure.Figure(figsize=(4, 2))
FigureCanvas(fig)

# for quick testing, I just use the defaults and set the txt
def make_img(txt: str, fileName: str = 'output', format: str = 'png', customDpi: int = 300, color: str = 'White'):
    then = default_timer()

    fig.text(0.5, 0.5, txt, color=color, fontsize=texFont.get_size_in_points(), fontproperties=texFont, verticalalignment='center', horizontalalignment='center')
    fileName += f'.{format}'
    
    fig.savefig(fileName, dpi=customDpi, transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1) # adjust padding here
    fig.clear()
    if default_timer() - then > 0.5:
        print('test', '%.4f' % (default_timer() - then))
    return fileName
```

I use the timer to track how long it often takes to save images. I only overwrite existing image files so I am not actually trying to create new files each time I use this function for my Kivy app.

I have a Kivy app that uses an Image for LaTeX math text and needs to frequently change it real-time and refreshes the image after calling make_img. However, I have noticed as I need longer strings that it begins to become laggy. I work with 5 images on the main Kivy script at once and even just one image can take up to 2.2 seconds. Even If I lower my DPI, it's still 2 seconds. If I attempt to load each image sequentially, this is too slow (but of course I don't have to do so).

The reason I am insistent on displaying math text in Kivy is that I was working on a time-limited  project but we don't have the time to switch frameworks. I am also most familiar with LaTeX formatting but want to still keep the ability to write math expressions and equations in a readable manner.

I was wondering if I can even do it without images but I have not found a way.

I tried using matplotlib in a variety of ways, coming to the fig as my most performant solution. I tried to convert the image into an array since I would work with long strings but Kivy doesn't accept it unless it's saved to the current directory. Kivy won't take images directly, only read from image files.

I thought about the math-text font idea but I can't find any good LaTeX math fonts right now to test with. I looked at another StackOverflow post that commented about it but the link they gave was just a 404 error.

I know that other frameworks could support LaTeX natively and directly but that isn't an option for me right now, even as much as I want to switch.

I simply just don't know what else to do, is there no other way?